# Should I use C++11 emplace_back with pointers containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Having a usual Base -> Derived hierarchy, like:

```
class Fruit { ... };
class Pear : Fruit { ... };
class Tomato : Fruit { ... };

std::vector<Fruit*> m_fruits;
```

Does it make sense (e.g: is performance better) to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`?

```
std::vector::emplace_back( new Pear() );
std::vector::emplace_back( new Tomato() );
```

Comment: you won't know until you benchmark/profile it

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit>>` to avoid memory leaks, then the answer is obvious.

Comment: I reader that emplace_back constructs itself the object, but in the case of pointers, I don't have a clue it if have sense.

Comment: @Zhen a pointer is an object. What it points to is another object

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pointers are scalar types and therefore literal types, and so copy, move and emplace construction (from an lvalue or rvalue) are all equivalent and will usually compile to identical code (a scalar copy).  `push_back` is clearer that you're performing a scalar copy, whereas `emplace_back` should be reserved for emplace construction calling a non-copy- or move- constructor (e.g. a converting or multi-argument constructor).

If your vector should hold `std::unique_ptr<Fruit>` instead of raw pointers (to prevent memory leaks) then because you're calling a converting constructor `emplace_back` would be more correct.  However that can still leak if extending the vector fails, so in that case you should use `push_back(make_unique<Pear>())` etc.

Comment: make_unique isn't in the standar, and it appears that emplace_back is same that push_back( std::move( X ) ) [i'm using gcc 4.7]

Comment: @Zhen: It may appear that way, but it's not. `emplace_back(new T())` can *leak*, while `push_back(make_unique<T>())` cannot. And yes, `make_unique` is missing by oversight, you can find implementations around the web.

Answer (score 35):

Don't use raw pointers, use `std::unique_ptr` like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit>> m_fruits;
```

And as you can't copy construct a `std::unique_ptr` you must use `emplace_back` (although you can use `push_back` with `std::move`).

```
m_fruits.emplace_back(new Pear());
m_fruits.emplace_back(new Tomato());
```

**Edit:**

As it appears that using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>::emplace_back` and `new` can leak if the `std::vector` needs and fails to reallocate memory, my recommended approach (until C++14 introduces `std::make_unique`) is to use `push_back` like this:

```
m_fruits.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Fruit>(new Pear()));
m_fruits.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Fruit>(new Tomato()));
```

Or using `std::make_unique`:

```
m_fruits.push_back(std::make_unique<Pear>());
m_fruits.push_back(std::make_unique<Tomato>());
```

Comment: Is the method in the Edit still be true in c++17 and c++20?

Comment: @r0ng Yes, as far as I know `vec.emplace_back(new Object())` can still leak in C++17 and C++2a if the vector fails to allocate memory for the new element. Use the suggestions in the edit.

Comment: Is there any drawback to use emplace_back with make_unique? like `m_fruits.emplace_back (std::make_unique<Tomato>());` @FelixGlas

Comment: @Defisher In practice, no. But it's a little bit misusing the api as `emplace_back` is meant for in-place construction and is taking the ctor arguments for the element type. E.g. if `Fruit` were a concrete class taking a parameter `const std::string& name`, then you would call `m_fruits.emplace_back("Pear")` etc. Back to the example - calling `m_fruits.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Pear>())` will behind the scenes pass on the argument to the in-place construction of the element `std::unique_ptr<Pear>(arg)`, i.e. (unnecessarily) using the copy/move ctor of the element type.