# Is this way acceptable for adding a unique_ptr to a vector?

Tags: c++

Say I have a Box. It contains Things, which are made by the `Box`, and only the `Box`. The Things are also uncopyable.

There is also an ownership relation, so I'd like to use `unique_ptr`s. (If the Box goes, everything goes with it.)

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Thing {
    friend class Box;
    public:
    ~Thing() {/* delete thing */};

    private:
    Thing() {/* construct thing */};
    Thing(const Thing& other) = delete;
    Thing& operator=(Thing&& other) = delete;
};

class Box {
    private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing> > contents{};

    public:
    void makeThing() {
        contents.push_back(nullptr);
        contents.back().reset(new Thing()); // I can live with the 'new' keyword here.
    }
};
```

My question is: **is it bad to add to the vector by pushing a `nullptr` then resetting it to a new object?** (Aside from the `new` keyword, which seems fine if the constructor doesn't throw?)

Note: I have already seen [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127107/private-constructor-and-make-shared) to overcome the private constructor and deleted copy semantics. But **is there anything dangerously wrong with what I wrote above?**

Note 2: Explicitly stating it here since it already caught a few people: `std::make_unique` **will not work** as the Thing constructor is private.

Comment: `Thing& operator=(Thing&& other) = delete;` - Why are they not moveable?

Comment: If you want a vector of unique_ptr why not add unique_ptr directly: `contents.push_back(std::make_unique<Thing>());` or `unique_ptr<Thing> t; ...; contents.push_back(std::move(t));`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector

Comment: `std::make_unique` won't work since the `Thing` constructor is `private`, will it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll totally admit, I didn't even notice. You're correct, it won't work. It will have to be done long-hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with this construct:

```
auto thing = std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing());
contents.push_back(std::move(thing));
```

Because this describes more what you are actually want to do. Your `Box` object creates a `Thing` object, passes the ownership to a `unique_ptr` and then you move that `unique_ptr` to `contents`.

And don't use `contents.emplace_back(new Thing());` one reason for sure it that it might leak. But the - imho - even more important part is readability and maintainability, and if you write `contents.emplace_back(new Thing());` then you need to check if `contents.emplace_back` really claims ownership (that `contents` is really of the type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing> >` and not `std::vector<Thing *>`, with `std::move(thing)` and `thing` being a `unique_ptr` it is clear that the ownership is moved.

The downside with your solution is that at the time of reading `contents.push_back(nullptr);` it is not clear why `nullptr` is added and you need to read the next line to understand why.

Comment: I think that a comment like "DO NOT replace with emplace_back. Temporary prevents leekage in case of exception." would be a very valuable addition to any variant of writing this code. (Adding this to your post, since I think that is the way to do it).

Comment: @n314159 you only mean replacing `contents.push_back(std::move(thing));` with `contents.emplace_back(new Thing());`? Because replacing `contents.push_back(std::move(thing));` with `contents.emplace_back(std::move(thing));` for the given code, should not result in leakage. Because any `unique_ptr` that is created on the way to insertion would have automatic storage duration.

Comment: `contents.emplace_back(std::move(thing))` is leak-free. The problem lies only with `contents.emplace_back(new Thing());`

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would use `make_unique`. But since the constructor of `Thing` is private and `Box` is friend, you need to construct the new `Thing` in `Box`, you can't use `std::make_unique`. But your approach is ... weird.

If you can't use `make_unique` it is very easy to create the possibility of leaks. For instance, the first obvious thing to do:

```
contents.emplace_back(new Thing()); // this can leak
```

**Will leak** (if the vector resizing fails)

There are solutions to solve this, like the longer:

```
contents.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing()));
```

Or reserving ahead:

```
contents.reserve(contents.size() + 1); // this prevents the amortized constant complexity
                                       // of `push_back`
                                       // resulting in worst performance
contents.emplace_back(new Thing);
```

But the problem still remains: It's easy to write a leaky code and the correct code does extra things which can look unnecessary so you need to comment and document their purpose so that the next programmer doesn't *optimize* them.

<del>The best</del> solution in my opinion is to make the constructor available to `make_unique`:

```
class Thing {

    friend std::unique_ptr<Thing> std::make_unique<Thing>();
    // ...
};

class Box {
    // ...

    void makeThing() {
        contents.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Thing>());
    }
};
```

Since making `make_unique` friend defeats the purpose of private constructor, I like more [n314159's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056618/2805305) of using a private `allocate_thing` method.

---

Thanks to all of the commenters down bellow for helping make this post correct and better.

Comment: `emplace_back` can leak, `push_back` doesn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783342/should-i-use-c11-emplace-back-with-pointers-containters

Comment: @Remellion `push_back` will also leak. `make_unique` is what prevents the leak, not the `push_back`

Comment: A `reserve` before would prevent emplace_back from throwing.

Comment: @bolov but in the above case, the `push_back` would throw before the creation of a new object on the heap and hence there would be no leekage.

Comment: @n314159 you are correct. Still thinking about the problem. Editing

Comment: Wouldn't `friend std::unique_ptr<Thing> std::make_unique<Thing>` defeat the purpose of the private constructor? Now everyone could construct `Thing` using `make_unqiue` and you could then make it `public` anyway.

Comment: @t.niese yep. Man, this is more of a challenge that it appears.

Comment: `contents.reserve(contents.size() + 1);` don't ever do that

Comment: @Sopel why? What is the matter?

Comment: you end up with O(n^2) operations for n calls

Comment: @Sopel Not necessarily. `reserve` needs to reserve *at least* n elements, but can reserve far more, and usually does. Still I share a bad feeling...

Comment: About `push_back`: It *is* safe, but not because of throwing before a new object is created (that's not the case!), but because it would accept a `std::unique_ptr` only, either as const reference (theoretically – we couldn't move out) or as rvalue reference. In both cases, the smart pointer needs to be created first before the argument can be passed to `push_back`...

Comment: @Aconcagua "and usually does" Which implementation does this? MSVC's and clang's don't.

Comment: @Sopel So far the bad the bad feeling... Then we'd have to go the classic variant (`if(size() == capacity() { reserve(capacity() * 2); }` or similar). Much easier to leave that to `push_back` – unless we knew the number of all existing elements in advance, then we could have one single `reserve` (and of course should do the same even with `push_back`).

Answer (score 3):

I think @t.niese has the way to do it. I want to add an alternative that hides the `new` a bit and maybe prevents anyone from refactoring with `emplace_back(new Thing)` (that can leak).

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Thing {
    friend class Box;
    public:
    ~Thing() {/* delete thing */};

    private:
    Thing() {/* construct thing */};
    Thing(const Thing& other) = delete;
    Thing& operator=(Thing&& other) = delete;

    static std::unique_ptr<Thing> allocate_thing() {
        return std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing);
    }
};

class Box {
    private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing> > contents{};

    public:
    void makeThing() {
        // DO NOT replace with emplace_back. Temporary prevents leekage in case of exception.
        contents.push_back(Thing::allocate_thing());
    }
};
```

What I don't like about this, is that one could imagine that `Thing::allocate_thing()` does some weird magic (which is not the case) and hence this makes the code more confusing.

I further want to say that maybe you should think about your design. While trying to reduce the access to `Thing` is good, maybe there is a better way to do that (maybe a anonymous namespace? Of course this will not prevent someone from creating an object if they can do a `decltype` of an element of the vector at some point). Maybe you can get some good recommnendations if you present your problem in more generality and not just ask for comments on this one solution.

Comment: Best solution IMO. I would consider naming it `Thing::make_unique` though.

Comment: Interesting approach, I like the idea behind it. I actually already knew about t.niese's solution before asking, but wondered specifically why my admittedly odd approach was not also fine. About the design: if you put the vector in `Thing` instead of `Box`, it becomes a well-known exercise. `Box` is a wrapper I want for the structure.

Comment: @Remellion I don't think I was clear enough. See the example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oaFynZ). Both things are not save against a user that really wants to get at your type. But you don't have to defend against a user determined to do something wrong. You should not be a security guard but more like a kindergarten teacher. (Note that I am not sure how my example works with ADL).

Comment: @n314159 I see your point, no need to guard vs malice. But as a beginner I have to defend against my future self, and as a beginner my toolkit for doing so is limited, so I appreciate answers and comments like this that explain other options.

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with this and just noticed that I landed approximately where @n31459 ended up. The only addition is that it uses perfect forwarding to the `Thing` constructors so you only need one `makeThing` function and factory function in `Thing` if you add more constructors later.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Thing {
public:
    ~Thing() = default;

private:
    explicit Thing(int Value) : value(Value) {}

    Thing(const Thing&) = delete;
    Thing(Thing&&) noexcept = delete;
    Thing& operator=(const Thing&) = delete;
    Thing& operator=(Thing&&) noexcept = delete;

    int value; // some data

    template<class... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<Thing> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Thing>{new Thing(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
    }

    friend class Box;
};

class Box {
public:
    template<class... Args>
    void makeThing(Args&&... args) {
        contents.emplace_back(Thing::make_unique(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> contents{};
};
```